# page working fine locally and on jsfiddle but not through GitHub

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

new here, and also new to the game. Weeks course done in house through work so far, loving it might i add. But through practice i have tried to create a page using bootstrap styling etc. I have an accordion on the page and also a carousel, neither work when hosted through git hub. Also when the navbar shrinks, the burger button is 'un-clickable'? Both work fine locally, and also on jsfiddle. Tried different combos of cdn placement but cant get anything working properly. Page has responsiveness, and columns seem to work fine. Not sure of next steps or what i need to share etc, im guessing my code? maybe i just c&p my .html page here? thanks in advance!

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap & JavaScript</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- My Style Sheet -->
  <link href="styles/bootstrap_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div style="padding-left: 15%; padding-right: 15%;">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EEF0EB;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="home.html"><img src="images/NE_logo (1).png" style="height: 70px; width: 70px;"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="font-size: 30px;">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="html.html">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="html+css.html">HTML&CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">BS&JS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="boot_JS1.html">BS&JS1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- header section -->
    <div class="container" style="font-family: Dongle; color: #153243; text-align: center;">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 style="font-size: 80px;">Made using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and JavaScript</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <p style="padding: 0; font-size: 40px;">This is a responsive webpage. Meaning that it will automatically adjust
        for different screen sizes and viewports. Change your window size to see how it 'reponds'.</p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!-- accordian -->
    <div class="accordion" id="bootsrap_accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
          <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne"
            style="font-size: 50px; color: #153243; background-color: #B4B8AB;">
            The Accordian
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
          aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne" data-bs-parent="bootsrap_accordion">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="font-size: 25px;">
            <strong>This is the body of the accordian. This first accordian body is shown by default, unless specified
              by
              the stylesheet otherwise. </strong>
            <p>The rest of the accordian can all be opened, and the window will remain open, until the header is clicked
              again to close it. This is another button style added externally through Bootstraps CSS. Also, the blue
              hue has been removed through CSS that is normally present (for accessibility reasons) when a header of an
              accordian is clicked.
              Removed on the external stylesheet: <br>
              <kbd style="font-size: 14px; padding: 0; background-color: #153243;">: focus { <br>
                outline: 0 !important; <br>
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important; <br>
                }
              </kbd>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo"
            style="font-size: 50px; color: #153243; background-color: #B4B8AB; background-color: #B4B8AB;">
            Paragraph Two
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
          aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="bootsrap_accordion">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="font-size: 25px;">
            Donec convallis nulla eget metus posuere, ut viverra turpis tristique. Ut volutpat est id sapien dignissim,
            eu interdum ex ornare. Phasellus auctor posuere neque, eu lacinia felis dapibus ac. Nunc porttitor, lacus
            nec condimentum rutrum, felis neque sollicitudin velit, sed pharetra massa mi quis massa. Morbi auctor felis
            diam, id tincidunt mauris dignissim vitae. Sed tincidunt sit amet felis eget vulputate. Mauris bibendum
            condimentum tincidunt. Pellentesque nulla ligula, porttitor in quam at, vehicula facilisis urna. Suspendisse
            molestie, libero et hendrerit porta, risus libero vehicula turpis, at mollis massa nulla in velit. Quisque
            ut gravida elit, molestie accumsan ante.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree"
            style="font-size: 50px; color: #153243; background-color: #B4B8AB;">
            Paragraph Three
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
          aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree" data-bs-parent="bootsrap_accordion">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="font-size: 25px;">
            Sed eget arcu tristique felis venenatis convallis in non magna. Praesent justo felis, bibendum vel nisi
            accumsan, venenatis cursus quam. Phasellus efficitur augue erat. Curabitur condimentum hendrerit quam non
            maximus. In volutpat tellus vitae nisi vulputate efficitur. Duis sodales sagittis rutrum. In quis velit
            posuere, rhoncus neque in, suscipit enim. Aliquam condimentum magna at euismod sollicitudin. Duis nulla
            urna, bibendum et justo vel, ullamcorper pretium erat. Sed imperdiet, purus vitae vulputate maximus, est
            diam malesuada nibh, non blandit nulla ante in dolor. Donec venenatis elit sed consectetur pellentesque.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingFour">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseFour" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseFour"
            style="font-size: 50px; color: #153243; background-color: #B4B8AB;">
            Paragraph Four
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
          aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingFour" data-bs-parent="bootsrap_accordion">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="font-size: 25px;">
            Nunc eu dolor dignissim, tristique turpis tristique, viverra arcu. Nulla scelerisque cursus ex, nec finibus
            turpis scelerisque eget. In porta felis eget facilisis bibendum. Aliquam id mi consequat, porttitor velit
            convallis, tincidunt urna. Quisque placerat tellus non mauris eleifend iaculis. Vivamus porttitor velit
            nunc, id facilisis erat scelerisque eget. Nunc rutrum laoreet augue sed egestas. Phasellus eget est
            fringilla odio finibus volutpat maximus ut mauris. Morbi sollicitudin semper nunc eget fringilla. Nam
            gravida dictum urna, at ullamcorper quam sagittis convallis. Aenean consequat ipsum a arcu efficitur
            ultricies. Sed gravida turpis in turpis posuere, sed faucibus mi consectetur.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <!-- Feature section-->
      <div class="container" style="font-family: Dongle; color: #153243; text-align: center;">
        <p style="padding: 0; font-size: 40px;">This next section is a responsive 'Feature' section. It uses Bootstrap's
          12 column grid system to re-size and maneuver the text and images depending on the screen width. </p>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="row featurette" style="color: #153243; ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 my-auto">
            <h1 style="font-size: 60px;"">Fred Again..</h1>
          <p style=" font-family: Dongle; color: #153243; font-size: 30px;">
              Frederick John Philip Gibson, known professionally as Fred Again or simply Fred, is a British record
              producer, singer, songwriter, multi-instrumentalist, and DJ.
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="images/carousel/fred_again.jpg" class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500"
              height="500" style="border-radius: 2.5%;" />
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="var(--bs-secondary-bg)" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr><br>
      <!-- new feature -->
      <div class="row featurette" style="color: #153243; font-family: Dongle;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2 my-auto">
            <h1 style="font-size: 60px;">Bicep</h1>
            <p style="font-family: Dongle; color: #284B63; font-size: 30px;">
              Bicep are an electronic music production and DJ duo from Belfast, Northern Ireland, consisting of Andrew
              Ferguson and Matthew McBriar. <br>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
            <img src="images/carousel/bicep.jpg" class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500"
              style="border-radius: 2.5%;" />
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="var(--bs-secondary-bg)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <!-- new feature -->
      <div class="row featurette" style="color: #153243; font-family: Dongle;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 my-auto">
            <h1 style="font-size: 60px;">Dave</h1>
            <p style="font-family: Dongle; color: #284B63; font-size: 30px;">
              David Orobosa Omoregie (born 5 June 1998), also known as Dave, is an English rapper. He has gained acclaim
              for his socially conscious lyricism and wordplay.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="images/carousel/dave.jpeg" class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500"
              style="border-radius: 2.5%;" />
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="var(--bs-secondary-bg)" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <!-- carousel -->
      <div class="container" style="font-family: Dongle; color: #153243; text-align: center;">
        <p style="padding: 0; font-size: 40px;">A simple carousel with <kbd
            style="font-size: 20px;">style="max-height...";</kbd> attributes to keep a consistant negative space from
          outer edge throughout the page.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
            aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/carousel/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="max-height: 749px;" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/carousel/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="max-height: 749px;" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/carousel/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="max-height: 749px;" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <br>

      <!-- footer -->
      <footer class="container-fluid bg-4"
        style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #153243; font-size: 15px;">
        <p style="float: right;"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p style="float: left;">&copy; Nik 2023 &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a> &middot;
          <a href="you_had_to.html">DONT CLICK</a></p>
      </footer>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dongle:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
  font: 20px Dongle;
  color: #EEF0EB;
  background-color: #EEF0EB;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #153243 !important;
  font-size: 30px !important;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 55;
  width: 55;
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  align-self: center !important;
  margin-top: 22px !important;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #B4B8AB, #153243, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

/* stops the accordian having a blue hue around clicked headers */
:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.footer {
  color: inherit !important;
}




.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
.featurette-heading {
  margin-top: 7rem;
}
```

nothing working correctly

Comment: Show your code, put a link to your page, anything?

Comment: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nikedmands/practice/main/boot_JS.html

Comment: saying comment too long when i paste code in? any other way i can share? i put the git hub preview up above

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76452792/edit) your question to include such details, can you try another CDN like Cloudflare, CSS: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` and JS: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js`? Also did you only include CSS?

Comment: hey, thanks for the advice... original post now should be edited? yes an external stylesheet was used, and attached in the original post now. thank you for helping thus far!

Comment: Why did you add `popper.min.js` where you already have `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`? Bundle includes *both* Bootstrap JS and Popper, therefore, you don't need it, also Bootstrap version 5 doesn't need jQuery anymore (unless you are using it for another purpose). And try to host your project on an actual thing like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) not just reading HTML file, and also currently `cdn.jsdelivr.net` is down for me (not sure if this is a global issue or something) that's why I suggested using something else like Cloudflare.

Comment: popper etc where just in there as i was adding cdn's like crazy to try and get it working. BUT, hosting on GitHub Pages seems to show the site working fine. so THANK YOU. im guessing its just because the other one i was using was so basic? Sorry, like i said, im new to this... but you have helped me hugely so THANK YOU (again)

Comment: I've wrote an answer so since it solved the problem upvote it (click the up arrow) as well as check the grey mark to mark this question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `popper.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` are included in `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` therefore you don't need individual `popper.min.js`. I should also say that [Bootstrap no longer requires jQuery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery) therefore this's not needed either.

And I guess `htmlpreview.github.io/` is for basic and vanilla HTML files therefore try to host it on a proper server like [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).